# Skip numbers in for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to skip values using a for loop. Something like

```
for (int i = 32; i <= 255 /* - but skip 128 to 159 */; i++) 
{
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write two loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(i >= 128 && i <= 159){
  // Will skip all these values.
  continue;
}
```

You can use the `continue` keyword within any loop in Java which will cause the control flow to *jump* back up to the immediate parent loop. So in your case, for all values of i between 128 and 159 the code block beneath will never be executed. Alternatively, if you don't like this solution then you could write two for loops and exclude the range between them, however this is arguably more simple to read and gives you more flexibility if you wish to skip multiple ranges or impose more specific conditions on when to skip values of `i`.

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of posting just code

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to split your loop into two loops (each with its own range), you can use `Stream`s:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(32,255)
         .filter(i -> i < 128 || i > 159)
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println((char) i));
```

Comment: And another 70 points leeched while there was a dupe, hope you are happy with them. I would expect people with so much rep to look for dupes first, instead of trigger happy posting.

Answer (score 1):

add a if statment:

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255; i++) {
      if(i < 128 || i > 159){
        char ascii = (char) i;
        System.out.println(ascii);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just like the answer from Adam, this doesn't explain what is done and why. Personally I don't like to perform the main code in yet another code block and `if...continue` makes it very clear that some parts of the code is skipped. Currently you have a part of the `for` block right behind the `if` block that is still executing, even if it is *currently* empty.

Answer (score 1):

There exist several solutions

1st you could create 2 loop (1 from 32 to 127 and one from 160 to 255)

--> That is maybe too specific to your case

2nd you could create an array containing the indexes you want to iter over and then you could loop over the array

3rd you could use the keyword `continue` to skip unsollicited iterations

```
 for(int i = 32; i <= 255; ++i){
   if(i>=128 && i <= 159) {
     continue;
   }
   // do your stuff
  }
```

Comment: Create separate answers instead of doing this. Currently all the answers are one each; then we can vote up the solution we like, which we cannot for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add a condition with "break" keyword like this :

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255 - but skip 128 to 159; i++) 
{
    if(i>128 && i<159){
        break;
    }
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

The keyword break will go through the current round of loop and go to the next

Comment: No, that's `continue`...